# how to add a contact to a group android

Tags: java, android, contacts

I have following code to add contact to a group into android's contact app / people app, it does add the group but not the contact in that group, what am i missing ? I am adding contact successfully also creating group, i do get the ids of both the things , i m using following code to associate the contact with the group but its not working , group is always empty.

```
 public Uri addToGroup(long personId, long groupId) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            personId);
    values.put(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,
            groupId);
    values
            .put(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

    return this.getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);

}
```

****update *****
Another thing i found is this group which i created doesn't get sync with google , probably thats the reason contacts aren't getting added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally could add a contact to group, this is what was required, create a contact that syncs with google account (mandatory), second create a group that can sync to default sync service and then add contact the way i am adding in above code.

if you are curious in knowing how to create group that can sync, here it is

```
public String createGroup(String name) {

    String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.Groups._ID,     ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE };

    try {
        ContentValues groupValues = null;
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        groupValues = new ContentValues();
        groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, name);
        groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.SHOULD_SYNC,true);
        cr.insert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, groupValues);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("########### Exception :",""+e.getMessage());
        return "1";
    }

    String groupID = null;
    Cursor getGroupID_Cursor = null;
    getGroupID_Cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,  GROUP_PROJECTION, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE+ "=?", new String[]{name}, null);

    getGroupID_Cursor.moveToFirst();
    groupID = (getGroupID_Cursor.getString(getGroupID_Cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));

    return groupID;


}
```

Comment: how to add contact to multi group?

Answer (score 1):

Use ContentProviderOperation for this.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
```

If the group is existing with `groupId`,

```
operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,
    groupId).build());
```

If group is not existing:

```
// create group and insert
ContentValues groupValues;
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

groupValues = new ContentValues();
groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, newGroupId);

try {
    cr.insert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, groupValues);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle
}

operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, newGroupId).build());
```

And, apply the changes:

```
ContentProviderResult[] cpr = context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
```

Comment: I have a question if the contact isn't synced with google account will it still get added to this group, using above method ?